QGIS: draw line from one point to many points in another layer using geometry generator
Using the geometry generator I would like to draw a line to each point that is within another layer.

ChatGPT gave me this, which I think is close, but not quite.
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        overlay_intersects('Centroids_10f9873c_2fbb_4e79_8698_c558fdf282c1', $geometry),
        make_line(
            $geometry,
            @element
        )
    )
)


This is going to draw a line from each point in one layer to all others within a max distance in another layer. My other layer is named layerB, limit:=-1 means no limit in the number of lines drawn within the distance.
collect_geometries(
array_foreach( array:=
overlay_nearest( layer:='layerB', expression:=$geometry, limit:=-1, max_distance:=15000), expression:=make_line($geometry, @element)))


